# Scene color/contrast changes based on camera perspective

Tags: rendering, materials, light

I have a multi-camera setup for viewing the scene at different perspectives. The top perspective view looks correct but my straight on view looks washed out without changing any of the settings. The cameras are at the same distance from the scene. I can change the render settings before I render but I would like to know why it looks so different.

Perspective View

[image: Perspective view]

Straight View with same render settings.

[image: Straight View]

Comment: Hello :). Isn't that just a light/world reflection?

Comment: If your material has some specular/glossy, that's totally normal that the reflection change according to the camera angle

Comment: Thank guys! There is just so much to learn when it comes to 3D design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lowered the "Specular" slider for the objects material that has the image using the shading tab. I did this for each object that has an image.

[image: specular]